# Unicode value \uXXXX to Character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, string-decoding

I've never done this before and am not sure why it's outputting the infamous `�` encoding character.  Any ideas on how to output characters as they should (ASCII+Unicode)?  I think `\u0041`-`\u005A` should print `A-Z` in UTF-8, which Firefox is reporting is the page encoding.

```
   var c   = new Array("F","E","D","C","B","A",9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
   var n   = 0;
   var d   = "";
   var o   = "";

   for (var i=16;i--;){
      for (var j=16;j--;){
         for (var k=16;k--;){
            for (var l=16;l--;){

               d =  c[i].toString()
                 +  c[j].toString()
                 +  c[k].toString()
                 +  c[l].toString();

               o += ( ++n + ": " 
                    + d   + " = " 
                    + String.fromCharCode("\\u" + d) 
                    + "\n<br />" );

               if(n>=500){i=j=k=l=0;} // stop early
            }
         }
      }
   }

   document.write(o);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `.fromCharCode()` function takes a number, not a string.  You can't put together a string like that and expect the parser to do what you think it'll do; that's just not the way the language works.

You could ammend your code to make a string (without the '\u') from your hex number, and call

```
var n = parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

to get the value. Then you could call `.fromCharCode()` with *that* value.

Comment: I'll have to try when I get home. For some reason I thought I remember someone building a string and using fromCharCode on it.

Comment: So basically, `\u` is only needed in open code and `fromCharCode` will convert integers into unicode characters, not just ASCII characters

Answer (score 11):

A useful snippet for replacing all unicode-encoded special characters in a text is:

```
var rawText = unicodeEncodedText.replace(
                  /\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/g, 
                  function (whole, group1) {
                      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(group1, 16));
                  }
              );
```

Using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: There is a `;` that shouldn't be there (the 2nd one)

Comment: Best answer in this case

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `\unnnn` syntax to create characters, you have to do that in a literal string in the code. If you want to do it dynamically, you have to do it in a literal string that is evaluated at runtime:

```
var hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
var s = "";
for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
  var hi = i >> 4;
  var lo = i % 16;
  var code = "'\\u00" + hex[hi] + hex[lo] + "'";
  var char = eval(code);
  s += char;
}
document.write(s);
```

Of course, just using `String.fromCharCode(i)` would be a lot easier...

Comment: I tried using a form of eval, which didn't work; I can't really remember what I did.  Perhaps it's because I was printing to the console at the time.  I see you did the range from 65..90; is there any range for that? - like I said, I'm wanting to see beyond just the ASCII, which I think stops at 255.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @vol7ron: Yes, I imagine you did two years ago, but someone downvoted yesterday.