# HTML Entity to Unicode conversion

Tags: javascript, unicode, html-entities

Is there some way to convert HTML Entities into unicode characters in Javascript?

I tried

```
var unicodeHtmlEntity = function (t) {
    numericValue = parseInt(t.slice(2, -1), 10);
    numericValue = numericValue.toString(16);
    return "\\u" + numericValue;
};
```

Where the function can be called like `&#8364;`, but returns the string `\u20ac`, not the unicode character for **€** . Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is the same with this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835317/unicode-value-uxxxx-to-character-in-javascript
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the vast majority of cases:

```
function unicodeHtmlEntity (t) {
    var numericValue = parseInt(t.slice(2, -1), 10);
    return String.fromCharCode(numericValue);
}
```

If you actually need to support characters in the "astral" planes, you can use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Getting_it_to_work_with_higher_values in place of `String.fromCharCode()`.

I presume you are aware that your code does not deal with hexadecimal entities, only decimal ones. To support those you could do something like:

```
function unicodeHtmlEntity (t) {
    var hex = t.charAt(2) === 'x';
    var base = hex ? 16 : 10;
    var pos = hex ? 3 : 2;
    var numericValue = parseInt(t.slice(pos, -1), base);
    return String.fromCharCode(numericValue);
}
```