# Unicode equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, arrays, html

Builtin function for Javascript equivalent for this code? i tried using CryptoJS but the bytes are not matching. Any builtin method available

```
byte[] tempBytes = (new UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes("TestWord");
```

I have used CryptoJS but still it doesn't provide same bytes

```
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/core-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-utf16-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script>
    var words=CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.parse('TestWord');
   console.log(words); 

</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode value \uXXXX to Character in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835317/unicode-value-uxxxx-to-character-in-javascript)

Comment: No its not duplicate i tried using this library still i can't get the same bytes please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used CryptoJS before 
CryptoJS `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.parse('TestWord');` returns object which has an array of words.
If you convert the words to byte using

`CryptoJS.util.wordsToBytes(words.words)` it will return the same bytes

i have made JSFiddle Here working as well [Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/sumeetkumar001/79o4xarL/41/)

Answer (score -1):

I use a class Crypto in c# and my code is:

```
byte[] tempByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myTextToEncryp);
```

Try this.