# Dynamic regex based string replacement in Java

Tags: javascript, java, regex, string, unicode

Inspired by this [regex-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17395203/1809463) to [a unicode question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3835317/1809463) I now have following javascript code,
which unescapes unicoded encoded character occurrences in strings.

```
var testString = "\\u53ef\\u4ee5NonUnicode\\u544a\\u8bc9\\u6211";
print(testString)

String.prototype.unescape = function() {
        return this.replace(/\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/g, 
                function (whole, group1) {
                    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(group1, 16));
                }
            );
    };

print(testString.unescape()) // outputs: 可以NonUnicode告诉我
```

I could not find a way in Java (1.7) to do this kind of dynamic regex replacement, there are only static approaches like [java.lang.String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or [java.util.regex.Matcher.group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)), which returns the group, but has no means to set it.

Is this even possible in Java? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I guess the problem is the same as in [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple using [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Matcher.appendTrail()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29):

```
// Compile the pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})");
// Create a matcher for our input
Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
// Create a buffer to hold the resulting string
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
// Iterate over matches
while(m.find()) {
  // Convert to UTF8 characters
  int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
  char[] chars = Character.toChars(codePoint);
  // Append to buffer
  m.appendReplacement(result, new String(chars));
}
// Append rest of string
m.appendTail(result);
// Display result
System.out.println(result);
```

You can test it [here](https://ideone.com/pPWHHO).

Comment: It won't work, if there are non unicode characters in the string. I'll revise the string in the question to emphasize that usecase.